# TapBarView adjust height according to content in it

Tags: flutter, mobile

i am trying to display items in Listview at first tab that I created. However when the tab is invisible unless I wrap TabBarView with a fixed sized container. What should I do to make this items visible without giving a fixed height to parent container?

I want red container to be dynamic according to content in it.

https://zapp.run/edit/zg5w062ig5x0?theme=dark&lazy=false

Unless the link goes down.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Tab inside body widget',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Tabs Example'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch, children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(height: 20.0),
          Text('Tabs Inside Body', textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22)),
          DefaultTabController(
            length: 4, // length of tabs
            initialIndex: 0,
            child: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch, children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                child: TabBar(
                  labelColor: Colors.green,
                  unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black,
                  tabs: [
                    Tab(text: 'Tab 1'),
                    Tab(text: 'Tab 2'),
                    Tab(text: 'Tab 3'),
                    Tab(text: 'Tab 4'),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: 400, //height of TabBarView
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  border: Border(top: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 0.5))
                ),
                child: TabBarView(children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text('Display Tab 1', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text('Display Tab 2', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text('Display Tab 3', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text('Display Tab 4', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                    ),
                  ),
                ])
              )
            ])
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever using a Widget like `Column`, `Row` or any other Widgets that has parent Widget with infinite height or width, use `Flex` or `Expanded` Widget as per your requirement

Sample Code : -

```
Expanded(child: TabBarView(children: [],))
```

Complete Code : -

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Tab inside body widget',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Tabs Example'),
      ),
      body: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
            const Text('Tabs Inside Body',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22)),
            DefaultTabController(
                length: 4, // length of tabs
                initialIndex: 0,
                child: Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        const TabBar(
                          labelColor: Colors.green,
                          unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black,
                          tabs: [
                            Tab(text: 'Tab 1'),
                            Tab(text: 'Tab 2'),
                            Tab(text: 'Tab 3'),
                            Tab(text: 'Tab 4'),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Container(
                              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.red,
                                  border: Border(
                                      top: BorderSide(
                                          color: Colors.grey, width: 0.5))),
                              child: const TabBarView(children: <Widget>[
                                Center(
                                  child: Text('Display Tab 1',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 22,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                ),
                                Center(
                                  child: Text('Display Tab 2',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 22,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                ),
                                Center(
                                  child: Text('Display Tab 3',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 22,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                ),
                                Center(
                                  child: Text('Display Tab 4',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 22,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                ),
                              ])),
                        )
                      ]),
                )),
          ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Output : -

[image]